# How to find my database host address for CI / CD?

Tags: postgresql, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment, knex.js

I'm going to conduct CI / CD in gitlab in AWS. My website contains a Postgresql database.

Question 1: But I don't know how to find the db host. Some say the host name is localhost, but I doubt it because I've deployed my website to AWS. Should it be elastic IP?

My .gitlab-ci.yml file is as follows:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - testing

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: firstdb
  POSTGRES_USER: johndoe
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
  POSTGRES_HOST: //I don't know

testing:
  services:
    - postgres:latest

  before_script:
    - npm install -g yarn 
    - yarn install
    - yarn knex migrate:latest --env testing
  stage: testing
  script:
    - yarn jest
```

Question 2: Also, should I change the database config of development, testing and production of knex.ts accordingly, so that it aligns with .gitlab-ci.yml?

My knex file is as follows:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: process.env.DB_NAME , //should I type actual data?
      user:     process.env.DB_USERNAME ,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    } 
  },
  testing:{
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST ,//should I type actual data?
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB ,
      user:     process.env.POSTGRES_USER ,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD 
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    } 
  },
  production: {
    client: "postgresql",
    connection: {
      database: process.env.DB_NAME ,//should I type actual data?
      user:     process.env.DB_USERNAME ,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD 
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: "knex_migrations"
    }
  }
};
```

Many thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Do you have the postgres connection string? Host is included in connection strings

Comment: @DevKyle How to call the connection string in terminal?

Comment: You wouldn't use connection string in terminal. I'm asking because your postgres account should show you what the connection string is, then you would be able to fill out the yml and knex files.

Comment: @DevKyle I'm new to web deployment. I wonder where I could find the host name. Should I type in the elastic IP address from AWS? Or type in "postgres"?

Answer (score 1):

The hostname is `postgres`. the hostname is derived from the image name.

explained here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-services-are-linked-to-the-job

Comment: When I call the host from terminal with \conninfo, it returns the socket rather than host. May I know why?   //
You are connected to database "firstdb" as user "johndoe" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432" //

Comment: So you can access the db through postures hostname?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by socket rather than host

Comment: I can access the db from remote server, but i need to deploy and do the CI / CD process. That's why I need to have the POSTGRES_HOST. And, I saw from other posts that the \conninfo command can return a host name, database name, user and port number. Mine returns a socket.....

Comment: Where are you running the command from. You might be connected to a local postgres?

Comment: I run in remote server. I input the ssh ubuntu@<xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - elastic ip address> beforehand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204665/discussion-between-arun-k-and-ronzenith).